# On OSX, the android sdk cannot find sdkmanager.jar -- path seems correctly set

Tags: android, macos, cordova

Using Cordova on OSX 10.9.3, I have downloaded and installed the android SDK (3.4.0) as well as the developer tools. The eclipse plug in runs fine. However in running the CLI Cordova interface, whenever I call android I get the android: can't find sdkmanager.jar error message. I have spent two days looking over SO and the web, and this seems to be a path problem. Here is the output of echo $PATH:

PowerBook-Work-4:~ lrlarson$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/androidSDK/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/androidSDK/sdk/tools:/Applications/androidSDK/sdk/tools:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/bin

The paths specified are accurate. I am stumped. It must be something obvious, but I am missing it. I appreciate any guidance, and apologize if this is a glaring noob error.

Comment: it's never something obvious with the Android SDK - The combination of that and Cordova sucks big time